# How to get the screen size regardless of device orientation in flutter

Tags: flutter

How to get the Screen height in flutter regardless of the device orientation? As I know with the media query the height changes with the device orientation.

Comment: Please describe more.Plz

Comment: You can check orientation with media query, so if orientation is landscape then width given by media query is height of your device.

Answer (score 8):

You can check if orientation is landscape or portrait:

```
Orientation currentOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation;
if(currentOrientation == Orientation.portrait){
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
} else {
   height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
 }
```